# How to group cron to plesk 11.0.9

Tags: cron, plesk, parallels

I'm using Plesk 11.0.9 and I try to create a couple of crons for each website but don`t know how to group them by a specified domain or something.. to have a better view of them.

I`m on Website & Domain > Scheduled Tasks and i see a "System user" then when i click it .. i could create all cron jobs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the best grouping you could do is to include domain name in a script name. Technically any script can access all/any domains under one system account - only you would know a particular script's function.